# Downloading an object byte range from Google Cloud Storage using Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to download a byte range from [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), using their [Java SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

I can download an entire file like this.

```
Storage mStorage; // initialized and working

Blob blob = mStorage.get(pBucketName, pSource);

try (ReadChannel reader = mStorage.reader(blob.getBlobId())) {
    // read bytes from read channel
}
```

If I want, I can `ReadChannel#seek(long)` until I reach a desired starting byte, and download a range from that point, but that seems inefficient (although I don't know exactly what's happening in the implementation.)

Ideally I would like to specify the `Range: bytes=start-end` header as [shown in the Google Cloud Storage REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#range), but I can't figure out how to set the header in Java.

How can I specify the byte range in the Java SDK Storage get call, or specify the header, so I can efficiently download the desired byte range?

Comment: Using the NIO interface you can get a SeekableChannel into your file, then call the position method to get where you want to read from. That's part of their Java SDK.

Comment: Since no one has an acceptable answer here, I add an issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/7625

Comment: Update: I trace the SDK code and post what I found in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you're trying to use Google Cloud's specific interface, but there is another way that perhaps you don't know about: Google Cloud can plug into Java's NIO interface. You can get a `Path` to a file on a bucket and use it as normal: get a [SeekableChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) into your file, then call the [`position(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html#position-long-) method to get where you want to read from.

Here is sample code I tested:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

(...)

    public static void readFromMiddle(String path, long offset, ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException {
        // Convert from a string to a path, using available NIO providers
        // so paths like gs://bucket/file are recognized (provided you included the google-cloud-nio
        // dependency).
        Path p = Paths.get(URI.create(path));
        SeekableByteChannel chan = Files.newByteChannel(p, StandardOpenOption.READ);
        chan.position(offset);
        chan.read(buf);
    }
```

You'll recognize this is normal Java code, nothing special there except perhaps the unusual way we make the `Path`. That's the beauty of NIO. To make this code able to understand "gs://" URLs, you need to add the google-cloud-nio dependency. For Maven it's like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-nio</artifactId>
      <version>0.107.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
```

And that's all.

[The documentation page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio) shows how to do it for other dependency managers and gives some additional information.

Comment: This is the solution I wound up going with after comparing this against using `blob.reader` and `FileOutputStream`. Not so rigorous testing indicated that `FileChannel.transferFrom` was 15 seconds faster than `FileOutputStream.write` for a ~400 MB download.

Comment: It should be noted that if you have `minifyEnabled = true` for any builds, you must include the proguard rules for google apis:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client-assembly/proguard-google-api-client.txt
They are probably overkill, but `ReadChannel.seek`/`FileChannel.position` will not function properly without some set of the these rules.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to just invoke `ReadChannel#seek(offset)`.

For example:

```java
        try (ReadChannel reader = blob.reader()) {
            // offset and readLength is obtained from HTTP Range Header
            reader.seek(offset);
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * 1024 * 1024);
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = reader.read(bytes)) > 0 && readLength > 0) {
                outputStream.write(bytes.array(), 0, (int) Math.min(len, readLength));
                bytes.clear();
                readLength -= len;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. However I went through a lot of debugging in my release build trying to figure out why MD5 checksums didn't match. It turns out that `minifyEnabled = true` in `build.gradle` breaks `reader.seek`. Applying the google-api-java-client proguard rules resolved the issue.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client-assembly/proguard-google-api-client.txt

Answer (score -1):

This is a good example to read the contents of an object.
In this link there are more code solutions:

[Stream file from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037540/stream-file-from-google-cloud-storage)

```
  /**
   * Example of reading a blob's content through a reader.
   */
  // [TARGET reader(String, String, BlobSourceOption...)]
  // [VARIABLE "my_unique_bucket"]
  // [VARIABLE "my_blob_name"]
  public void readerFromStrings(String bucketName, String blobName) throws IOException {
    // [START readerFromStrings]
    try (ReadChannel reader = storage.reader(bucketName, blobName)) {
      ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024);
      while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
        bytes.flip();
        // do something with bytes
        bytes.clear();
      }
    }
    // [END readerFromStrings]
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to download an entire object (as shown in my question.) The thing which I don't know is _how to request a specific section of an object_ by adding a request header with a byte range to the request.

Comment: As of the date of this post, calling `reader.seek(int position)` before the while loop should start downloading from the byte provided as the position argument. Keep in mind that if you have `minifyEnabled = true` set for builds you must apply the google-api-java-client proguard rules or seek will not function properly.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that you cannot fine-grained control of the range header in the current Java SDK implementation.

You can set the starting position by `ReadChannel#seek(offset)`, but not the ending position.

Inside of the Java SDK, it will set the range header as `Rrange:$offset-$(offset+bufferSize)`.

https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/blob/master/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/spi/v1/HttpStorageRpc.java#L732

A workaround is wrapping the `ReadChannel` by yourself, and close the connection while it reaches the expected ending position. Code snipplet:

```
class GSBlobInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final ReadChannel channel;
    private long start = 0;
    private long end = -1;
    private InputStream delegate;

    public GSBlobInputStream(ReadChannel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public GSBlobInputStream(ReadChannel channel, long start, long end) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        init();
        return delegate.read();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        init();
        return delegate.read(b);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        init();
        return delegate.read(b, off, len);
    }

    /**
     * Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
     *
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.close();
        }
    }

    private void init() throws IOException {
        if (delegate != null) {
            return;
        }

        channel.seek(start);

        delegate = Channels.newInputStream(channel);
        if (end != -1) {
            delegate = ByteStreams.limit(delegate, end - start + 1);
        }
    }


}
```

Note that in this approach, your will have 15MiB - 1 byte overhead in the worst case, since the default buffer size is 15MiB.

Comment: I was running into issues with `seek` as well in release builds with `minifyEnabled = true` set. I wasn't able to diagnose what exactly was going wrong (whether seek was not moving the position to the new index or if it was reading past the end of the buffer) but MD5 checks failed consistently on partial downloads that had been resumed. I resolved the issue by applying the google-api-java-client proguard rules.